# Can't fix a NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

I am an amatuer programmer who had just finished working on his app and is now debugging; until the app crashed without asking :(.

I did a stack trace from the lolcat and the following achieved a NullPointerError in the ContextWrapper.

```
@Override
public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
    return mBase.getPackageManager();
}
```

But I can't see a problem with it. The app code is below:

```
package com.example.denny.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.Manifest.permission;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    if (pm.checkPermission(permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        alertboxGPS();
    }
    mHandler = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View view) {
                                   Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                           .setAction("Action", null).show();

                               }
                           }

    );
    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
    return super.getPackageManager();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    //Also, chuck the subroutine settings here. :3
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

protected void alertboxGPS() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your Device's GPS is Disabled")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setTitle("** Gps Status **")
            .setPositiveButton("Gps On",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // finish the current activity
                            // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // cancel the dialog box
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

protected void alertboxViolation() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Please stop walking. You may get in an accident.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle("Walking Warning")
            .setPositiveButton("Stop Walking",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // finish the current activity
                            // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // cancel the dialog box
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

protected void alertboxGranted() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Access Granted")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setTitle("Access to GPS")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // finish the current activity
                            // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // cancel the dialog box
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

//Some Default Integers
int ViolationLimit = 10;
int SpeedLimit = 100;
int ExceedInstance = 0;

//Default Value
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location1;
Location location2;

private boolean canGetLocation() {
    return(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private double GetSpeed(Location location1, Location location2) {

    if (location1 == null) {

        location1 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        location2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } else {
        location1 = location2;

        }
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                alertboxGranted();
        }
        location2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    double Distance;
    Distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
    double Speed = Distance / mInterval;
    return Speed;
}


private int Judge(double Speed, int ViolationLimit, int SpeedLimit, int ExceedInstance) {
    if (Speed >= 1 && Speed <= SpeedLimit) {
        ExceedInstance += 1;
    }

    if (ExceedInstance >= ViolationLimit) {
        alertboxViolation();
    }
    return ExceedInstance;
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
}

private int mInterval = 3000; // 3 seconds by default, can be changed later
private Handler mHandler;
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateStatus();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
    }
};

private void updateStatus() {
    //Is used for updating mInterval
}

void startRepeatingTask() {
    double Speed = GetSpeed(location1, location2);
    Judge(Speed, ViolationLimit, SpeedLimit, ExceedInstance);
    mStatusChecker.run();
}
```

}

Lolcat:

```
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41967898)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.denny.myapplication/com.example.denny.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:94)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.denny.myapplication.MainActivity.getPackageManager(MainActivity.java:63)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.denny.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:83)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
10-17 10:41:39.663 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-17 10:41:42.556 7874-7874/com.example.denny.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7874 SIG: 9
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you add your stack trace of crash aslo ?

Comment: Post please your stack trace

Comment: "lolcat" is really how it should be named :)

Comment: show your logcat please

Comment: Use after oncreateview `mHandler = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask();`

Comment: (To Selven) Oh, yes. That is why I said that I am an amature. I'm so sorry to fail to meet your social expectations, but I have to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, you may call location1 and location2 when they are not initialised in your method `startRepeatingTask()`. They need to be initialised and handled for a null exception like you have in `getspeed`.

```
Location location1 = null;
Location location2 = null;

/.../

private double GetSpeed(Location location1, Location location2) {

    if (location1 == null) {

        location1 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        location2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } else {
        location1 = location2;
    }

/.../


void startRepeatingTask() {
    if (location1 != null && location2 != null) {
        /.../
        double Speed = GetSpeed(location1, location2);
        Judge(Speed, ViolationLimit, SpeedLimit, ExceedInstance);
        mStatusChecker.run();
}
```

After seeing your stacktrace:
The null pointer exception is showing up on both lines where you've used:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
```

Firstly:
Declare `PackageManager pm;` **Once** in your class scope and then initialise it in your 
`onCreate`.

```
pm= getPackageManager();
```

By declaring a PackckageManager pm = getPackageManager() within your Activity class and within your onCreate, do you realise that you are dealing with two separate instances with the same name and differing scope within your application.

I am confused by your code, to be completely honest.

So I suggest the following apart from what I have said above, you need to research and try and understand the following:

1. Scope
2. Initialising objects -> calling an uninitialised object will cause a nullpointerexception.
3. PackageManagers

This will really help your progress. It's very hard to explain all this within this site. So I have provided some links to go with each point.

1. [java-made-easy.com/variable-scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)
2. [Object initialization in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html)
3. [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html), [how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android) and [the github repository](https://github.com/javatechig/Advance-Android-Tutorials/tree/master/ListInstalledApps)

Comment: It still comes up with the NullPointer. Is the error because I did not import the Location into startRepeatingTask?

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep those in mind. Sorry if my code is confusing. I was pressed for time; and it was my first app. I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: Also; thank you for your detailed answer. Not only did you provide a solution to my problem, but you ran a full diagnosis of my code. Thank you so much!